# Python thread is being suspended if computer is idle for a long time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am developing a whatsapp web automation application using python-3.6 and `tkinter`, I have created a thread to send whatsapp message.

**Problem:**
Thread is not sending any message if computer is idle for a long time and if there is no message to send.

tried to check if thread is not alive then restart it

```
def WhatsappSending(self):
    self.isUserOnline()
    while True:
        if self.t1.isAlive():
            a = d.SendingWhatsapp()
        else:
            self.t1.start()
```

**Expected Output:** 
Thread should be resume or start again.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: An already started thread cannot be started again no matter it is alive or not.  You need to recreate the thread.

Comment: okay let me try, will update you soon.